# Start adress in process Win32

Tags: visual-c++

Please tell me by what criteria does the WaitForDebugEvent function find the starting address in the body of the process?

f we look at the statistics of such executable files and modules, then there is a discrepancy! The MFC exe file gives one
assembly block, the C++ Builder exe file gives another assembly block. And PDC Visual Prolog gives another completely
different block! And understand how Windows determines the starting address)!?

Comment: It is in the executable file header, [AddressOfEntryPoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format#optional-header-standard-fields-image-only) field.   It almost always refers to the runtime support library that the program uses, initializing it before calling the program's start function.  Different programming tools have different runtime implementations.